# Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline

Tags: python, repl

I've got this problem with my 25.1 and Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.10, but I don't see it being solved anywhere. Wondering what the latest status was. Reproducing:

```
> emacs -Q --eval '(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")'
```

then

`M-x run-python` gives

```
Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native’ was t and "python3" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.
```

I saw one idea where an `M-x find-function python-shell-completion-native-try` would pull up the function from deep `(/usr/local/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/progmodes/python.el.gz` and the very last line was supposed to be `nil "_")))` and not `nil "")))`. Another conversation [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24401) talks about changing `inputrc`

> I switched to another user and I was able to use `run-python' without 
>   any warnings. Turns out it was my readline settings. Bash 4.3 added a
>   new readline feature: "set colored-stats on" which I had in .inputrc
>   Removing that line fixed my issue, I think this should be reproducible
>   for all.

Anybody know what the latest is on this? BTW, running Python2 (`(setq org-babel-python-command "python2")`) doesn't have this problem.

Comment: The Emacs bug you linked to is marked as solved for 25.2 (not released yet), so you should expect it to still be present in 25.1. You can try the pretest version (25.1.9x).

Comment: Know when 25.2 is out?

Comment: Maybe a month or so? You can try the pretest (25.1.91) now http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/

Comment: I’ve got the same symptoms ("Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline") running Python 3.6.0 and GNU Emacs 25.2 RC1 on Windows 10, so either the problem isn’t solved yet, or maybe it is a different problem?

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to get a 25.2 rc, you can apply the bug fix by adding this to your init.el file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'python
  (defun python-shell-completion-native-try ()
    "Return non-nil if can trigger native completion."
    (let ((python-shell-completion-native-enable t)
          (python-shell-completion-native-output-timeout
           python-shell-completion-native-try-output-timeout))
      (python-shell-completion-native-get-completions
       (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
       nil "_"))))
```

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25753#44

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For some reason adding this `(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)` to my `init.el` file worked, without requiring the code above.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé that suppresses the warning, but you don't get native completion. If you're [on Windows, that's the right thing to do](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35969/5296).

Comment: Even on Emacs 26.1 I still get this issue.

Comment: Also on Emacs 26.2 , and this answer still works.

Comment: @ZoeRowa It won't break on Emacs 25.2 and above, but it doesn't do anything useful (since it's just installing the version of that function from 25.2).

Comment: same issue on Emacs 27.1... did as @GuilhermeSalomé recommended, and warnings went away.

Answer (score 5):

I had this disturbing warning in Emacs 25.1 too.

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24401 has proper solution to enable `colored-stats` only for Bash:

```
$ cat ~/.inputrc
$if Bash
set colored-stats on
$endif
```

Comment: Thank you - I would never have worked out my `.initrc` was what  broke my \*Python\* repl

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Emacs 27 and Python 3.9, on Debian 11.
My workaround was to wrap my ~/.inputrc with `$if term=dumb`, `$else`, and `$endif`.  This disables all my psql and python tricks when run inside comint.el (which sets $TERM=dumb), but keeps them when run directly in a regular terminal.

Answer (score 1):

A `pip install readline` did the job for me. Completion within python code blocks is pretty neat to have...