# Emacs 25.1 & Python 3.6.0 Integration [Newbie]

Tags: init-file, python, elpy, jedi

**Preface**:

I've been dabbling with python programming for a mere few months now. Previously, I spent most of my programming time using C# with Visual Studio. In the Python world, I've been using PyCharm for my projects. It has excellent code-completion (much like the IntelliSense I'm used to) and a nice level of customizability. However, at the end of the day, I want something a little bit lighter and less clunky. I have seen videos of developers using Emacs with Python and I'm quite interested in learning it.

**Setup**:

- Python 3.6.0 is installed.
- I have downloaded [emacs-25.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.zip](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) from the Emacs website.
- I have created a folder `C:\emacs` and extracted the zip file to this location
- I have identified the Emacs home folder as `C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`
- I have created an `init.el` file in this directory since one did not exist

**Python Integration**:

Now, this is where I'm struggling. I'm still extremely new to the software so it's a bit hard to piece together information from the internet. Using [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) I have developed a baseline `init.el` file. Due to my reputation points, I cannot include a third link here. The Gist containing my `init.el` file is commented below.

When I open Emacs and open a python file, editing works. However, I'm running into the issues outlined below:

1. `C-c C-c` returns an error. It seems to be a relatively wide-spread error upon Googling. By simply typing `C-c C-c` again, the shell will appear with the code being executed; however, it gives me the line `python.el: native completion setup failed`

**Edit**: The error is `Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support
    readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native’ was t and "python3" is not
    part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.
    Native completions have been disabled locally.`

2. Python autocomplete doesn't seem to be working properly. When using PyCharm, I get a much, much more robust offering of completions. In the case of Emacs, if I begin typing something such as `from tkint` it will not suggest `tkinter`. Similarly, if I start typing `from math import a` it will not suggest `abs`. I'm not sure at all how to configure Python autocompletion. I've read a few things about using `pip install jedi` and so on, but I haven't done any of that.

I realize this may be just as much a python question as an Emacs question in some regards. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30970/5296

Comment: Have you set up a default virtualenv for elpy yet or are you still using system python?

Comment: `init.el` file: https://gist.github.com/JoshuaGranger/27f897fd711bd15c4da896fb59871c2a

Comment: @Narlisarc: No, I have not. I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: basically run virtualenv to create a python environment and then add this: 
(pyvenv-activate "path/to/your/virtualenv/") to your init file after you enable elpy. Then install jedi or rope to that environment using pip.

Comment: "`C-c C-c` returns an error. It seems to be a relatively wide-spread error upon Googling." - so what's the error then? Don't keep us in suspense!

Comment: @npostavs my apologies. Edited.

Comment: Seems like it could the same problem as the link in my first comment then, unless there is some additional Windows-specific problem.

Comment: To all saying the issue is fixed, I am on OSX Catalina with Emacs 26.3 and the issue is still about.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be bug in emacs and its fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/dbb341022870ecad4c9177485a6770a355633cc0).

As npostavs mentioned, you can use

```
(with-eval-after-load 'python
  (defun python-shell-completion-native-try ()
    "Return non-nil if can trigger native completion."
    (let ((python-shell-completion-native-enable t)
          (python-shell-completion-native-output-timeout
           python-shell-completion-native-try-output-timeout))
      (python-shell-completion-native-get-completions
       (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
       nil "_"))))
```

You can read entire [discussion here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/887).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
 python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```

For python 3.6 I found jedi with company to be the most reliable but others may have different experiences. "mypath" below are the paths to packages I've created that I want autocomplete.

```
(use-package company-jedi      
 :config
  (setq jedi:environment-virtualenv (list (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments/")))
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
  (setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
  (setq jedi:use-shortcuts t)
  (setq jedi:server-args
  '("--sys-path" "mypath1"
    "--sys-path" "mypath2"))

  (defun config/enable-company-jedi ()
    (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'config/enable-company-jedi))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04, I added `python-setuptools` **in addition** to `python3-setuptools`.
Problem disappeared.

(I'm using Emacs 25.3.2, from the stable *kelleyk* PPA; Spacemacs user)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding programming Python in emacs, be sure to check out [LSP](https://github.com/emacs-lsp). It is a wonderful initiative that is well maintained and supported.